# crontab is not deleting the files in linux

Tags: linux, cron

I am trying to delete all the pdf files which are more than 30 days old at 11:30 PM

I added the below given code in crontab

```
30 23 * * * find /var/www/html/site/reports/ -name "*.pdf" -type f -mtime +30 | xargs -I {} rm -f {} \;
```

But it doesn't delete the files.

Can you please check what the issue is?

The crontab details

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 532 Sep 30 11:14 crontab
```

One of the files which i need to delete

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache apache 15215 Jul 25 11:24 sales_report.pdf
```

Comment: `+30` means **more** than 30 days old. So the files that are exactly 30 days old won't be deleted.

Comment: You don't need `\;` at the end -- that's for when you use `find -exec`, it's not part of `xargs`. But why don't you just use `-exec`?

Comment: Also, some versions of `find` have a `-delete` option that deletes the file.

Comment: @Barmar, yes, I need to delete the files more than 30 days old. I updated the question. sorry about the confusion.

Comment: I know that's what you meant. My point is that it doesn't include the files that are 30 days old, it starts with the files that are 31 days old.

Comment: Do any of your filenames have spaces in them?

Comment: `cron` sends email with any output from the command. Are you getting any error messages from this?

Comment: @Barmar, it is okay if it starts with the files that are 31 days old. file names do not have space in them. how do i see the error messages?

Comment: Like I said, the error messages will be emailed to the user that the cron job is running as.

Comment: -rw-r--r--.   1 root root      532 Sep 30 11:14 crontab
- this is crontab details

Comment: So have you checked root's mail?

Comment: yes, i checked. but there is no recent emails related to this.

Comment: -rw-r--r--  1 apache  apache  15215 Jul 25 11:24 sales_report.pdf - this is one of the files which i need to delete

Comment: Are you sure the cron job is even running? Add an `echo` statement to it.

Comment: @Barmar, i added root user-name and it works now. "30 23 * * * root find /var/www..."

Comment: Ahah, it wasn't obvious that you were talking about `/etc/crontab` rather than a per-user crontab file.

Comment: sorry @Barmar, I am new to cron and I was not aware that i need to specifically mention /etc/crontab

Answer (score 1):

You missed user and PATH. This may help

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root
HOME=/

30 23 * * * root find /var/www/html/site/reports/ \( -name "*.pdf" \) -type f -mtime +30 -exec rm {} \; >> /tmp/debug_cron 2>&1
```

And then check /tmp/debug_cron

Comment: Thanks @aldebober, which one is more appropriate among the two of these. 1. "30 23* * * root find /var/www/html/site/reports/ -name ".pdf" -type f -mtime +30 | xargs -I {} rm -f {} \;" 2. "30 23 * * * root find /var/www/html/site/reports/ ( -name ".pdf" ) -type f -mtime +30 -exec rm {} \;"

Comment: The exec option is better

Comment: can you please tell me the reason?

Comment: This is the option of find command. You don't need to start any other processes because find can do it. You can use all you like ))) It's just usual practice

Answer (score 0):

I have this working a a linux box.

```
30 23 * * * find /var/www/html/site/reports/ \( -name "*.pdf" \) -type f -mtime +30 -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: You don't need parentheses when there's only one test inside it.

Comment: i added root user-name and it works now. I have one more question. both jobs (1. the one i mentioned, 2. the one @Jason mentioned) are working. which one is more appropriate? "30 23* * * root find /var/www/html/site/reports/ -name "*.pdf" -type f -mtime +30 | xargs -I {} rm -f {} \;" and "30 23 * * * root find /var/www/html/site/reports/ \( -name "*.pdf" \) -type f -mtime +20 -exec rm {} \;"